# Google Colab stops the cell that is running my code

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using tensorflow 1.15.2. I get through a number of iterations, then it shows ^C at the end, signifying that it stopped the cell. It shouldn't be a problem with memory because I am also able to run this locally, with a 6Gb Geforce RTX 2060.

This is the Colab notebook (it gets stuck in the last cell). https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IP7eXYWxBusyR41Q7-ifHnjtnamRAqca#scrollTo=g2nheFTLpqo0

Comment: Not reproducible because we don't have access to the module and the files.

Comment: @runDOSrun I don't understand your comment, the notebook is open, I've tested it from a private window and it's accessible. The github project it uses is public, and the google drive files it uses are also public (actually that code wouldn't work even for me otherwise)

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. Sorry but for some reason the notebook lacked a lot of the code it has now when I clicked on it. Anyway, I've run your notebook and the issue is RAM (not VRAM). Colab has 12.72 GB RAM and it gets exhausted rather quickly.  You can check this for yourself if you watch the RAM bar in the top right. It aborts once it allocates too much. If your computer can run it, you can connect it to a local runtime.